# No space on Mac

Tags: macos

Strange issue. I have 0 free space on my Mac. Everything is taken by System Data.

When checking by Disk Inventory X, looks like it created 4 Applications folder inside of each, see screenshot.

Anyone got an idea what happened here? :D

Ps. no, I don't know when it happened. This is a device connected to the work domain group.

[image]

Comment: Can you run `df -hg; diskutil list` and add the output **as text** to the question, with an [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/459072/9058)?

Comment: There shouldn't be a System folder insider /Applications. But I'd also beware of file utilities not coping with aliases that might be recursive.

Comment: Fyi, I've rm -rf additional System folder, I have 300GB back and OS is still working 